# Is there a Best Practice standard for providing OAUTH2 security over a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: oauth-2.0, kubernetes

I am starting to experiment with Oauth2 authorisation for a Kubernetes cluster.

I have found a good Oauth2 identity provider using [UAA](https://github.com/hortonworks/docker-cloudbreak-uaa)

My original intention was to deploy this into a Kubernetes cluster, and then allow it to provide authentication over that cluster. This would provide a single sign on solution hosted in the cloud, and enable that solution to manage Kubernetes access as well as access to the applications running on my cluster.

However, when thinking this solution through, there would seem to be some edge cases where this kind of configuration could be catastrophic. For instance if my cluster stops then I do not think I will be able to restart that cluster, as the Oauth2 provider would not be running, and thus I could not be authenticated to perform any restart operations.

- Has anybody else encountered this conundrum ?
- Is this a real risk ?
- Is there a 'standard' approach to circumvent this issue ?

Many Thanks for taking the time to read this !

Comment: I take it you mean for administering the cluster (including using the kubectl command-line client) and accessing its APIs. On that see https://thenewstack.io/kubernetes-single-sign-one-less-identity/ as it explains a range of options. For apps deployed within the cluster you might well want to deploy an identity provider in the cluster and let the apps use that. Naturally there are a range of different identity providers and approaches to authentication out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes support multiple authentication( ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/).

You can enable multiple of them. You can log into kubernetes cluster using any of the them(if they enabled and configured correctly) .

According to kubernetes documentation: **When multiple authenticator modules are enabled, the first module to successfully authenticate the request short-circuits evaluation. The API server does not guarantee the order authenticators run in.**

So, if you enable multiple authentication, i think you are fine. I am using kubernetes cluster. In that cluster certificates authentication and [webhook token authentication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#webhook-token-authentication) using [guard](https://github.com/appscode/guard) is enabled. And this [guard](https://github.com/appscode/guard) is running in that kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 1):

The use of UAA consists of two 2 procedures—authentification and authorization—where the latter allows for performing certain actions within a cluster. They are used through the kubectl command-line tool.

One can use **2 existing modules of authorization** ([ABAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/abac/) and [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)). [Here](https://www.altoros.com/blog/configuring-uaa-to-provide-a-single-entry-point-for-kubernetes-and-cloud-foundry/) you can find a side-by-side comparison of these two options where the author vouched for the RBAC mode as it "doesn’t require the API server to be restarted every time the policy files get updated".

If I understood your question right, [this article](https://www.altoros.com/blog/configuring-uaa-to-provide-a-single-entry-point-for-kubernetes-and-cloud-foundry/) may be of help.